# É possível uma função JavaScript chamar um método que esta no code behind da página?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net, button

Tenho um botão e eu queria programar o `click` dele, e quando uso um `<asp:Button>` eu programo o `click` dele no *code behind*. Agora estou usando um `button` normal.

Não sei quase nada de JavaScript e queria programar ele no *code behind* também. Teria como eu criar uma função JavaScript chamando um método C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º passo, no **server-side** adicione o metodo.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Message(){
     return " MENSAGEM ";
}
```

2º passo, procure a tag `<asp:ScriptManager ID="..." runat="server"  />`    e adicione `EnablePageMethods="true"`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

3º passo, vamos criar um metodo no javascript

```
function getMessage() {
    PageMethods.Message(OnGetMessageSuccess, OnGetMessageFailure);
}
```

4º passo, vamos usar um botao normal...

```
<input type='submit' value='Get Message' onclick='getMessage();return false;' />
```

Comment: Quando eu clico no botão ele aparece o erro : Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined.

Vi o erro pelo F12 do navegador

Comment: procure a tag `asp:ScriptManager` no seu `.aspx` e adicione a propriedade `EnablePageMethods="true"`

Comment: Deu certo, mas eu criei um método que retorna um inteiro (1+1) e coloquei ele em uma `var` no javascript e o alert para mostrar essa variável, mas ele mostra `undefined`, sabe o que pode ser ?

Não sei se fiz certo mas coloquei assim no javascript `var result = PageMethods.PesquisarClick();`

Comment: Se deu certo pode marcar como resposta correta ou dar um `+`

Pra te facilitar encontrei este [tutorial](https://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/) , siga as instrucoes que vai conseguir

Answer (score 3):

Sim. Você vai precisar do [AJAXExtensionsToolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883) no seu projeto.

Primeiro, coloque em sua página o seguinte:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
    EnablePageMethods="true" 
    EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
```

No *Code Behind*, crie o método estático:

```
using System.Web.Services;

[WebMethod]
public static string MeuMetodo(string nome)
{
    return "Oi, " + nome;
}
```

Para chamar, você pode fazer assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#botao").click(function () {
        PageMethods.MeuMetodo("Cigano Morrison Mendez");
    });
</script>
```

Pro exemplo, suponho que tem jQuery no seu projeto.

Answer (score 3):

Se sua implementação está restrita a uma página ASP.NET com codebehind, você pode implementar uma chamada a um WebMethod da seguinte maneira:

**Marque o método como um *WebMethod***. Ele precisa ser, necessariamente, um método estático.

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string MetodoASerChamado()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

**Chame a função diretamente** a partir da implementação javascript.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "Default.aspx/MetodoASerChamado",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Diretamente é impossível mas o ASP.Net tem facilidades para a chamada do cliente invocar o que precisa:

```
<asp:Button ID="botao" OnClick="botao_Click" runat="server" />
```

Então no *Code-behind*:

```
protected void botao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //faça o que quer aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ButtonCodeBehind.cs).

Comment: É que estou usando um botão pronto do bootstrap então ele vem como button, e se eu trocar para asp:button, ele não vai ficar igual.

Comment: Você deveria ter informado isto na pergunta. Eu respondi o que você perguntou.

Comment: @LucasSousa voce pode utilizar como o bigown colocou só usar o css do bootstrap     <asp:Button ID="botao" OnClick="botao_Click"  CssClass="btn btn-small btn-primary" runat="server" />